# Finding index of NSMutableDictionary inside an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary with a specific `key` and `value`. This dictionary is inside an NSMutableArray. I want to update the dictionary with a specific key which is at a certain index inside the array. I want to find the index of this dictionary object. Currently, my dictionary is at index 0 and my `editingIndexPath` is 1 which is of NSIndexPath type, so `editingIndexPath.row` doesn't help me.

My code is as follows:

```
    //UpdatedDateAndTime is the NSMutableArray.
    //selectedDay is a NSString object.
    //dateKeySelected is also a string key.

    [[updatedDateAndTime objectAtIndex:editingIndexPath.row] setObject:selectedDay forKey:dateKeySelected];
```

My problem is that I want to get the right index of the dictionary that is found.

Comment: What is the issue with the above code ? Does it set the key ? Isn't the index of the dictionary same as editingIndexPath.row ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri... No! What if the dictionary was already there in the array. For me, it was at `index` with value `0` whereas in the tableview, my cell corresponding to this dictionary is `editingIndexPath.row` which is `1`. I want the array index corresponding to the dictionary.

Comment: How do you know that's the one at index 1? How do you compare the dictionaries?

Comment: @Larme..My comment might give you the answer.

Comment: @Ron does NSMutableArray contains different classes or all NSMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer used to be a for loop with a counter, but you're in luck: NSArray has a new method, [indexOfObject:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1417076-indexofobject?language=objc), which should do the trick just fine:

```
NSUInteger i = [myArray indexOfObject:@{myKey:myValue}];
```

Swift: [index(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1417076-index)

Comment: I get the index value this long. '9223372036854775807`

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the right index. Why I was getting this index was because I was not passing the correct dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

If your array contains just one special `NSMutableDictionary` then use below code. I didn't test it but the idea is to search `NSMutableDictionary` class in the array. And you have to do this search in `indexPath` which equals to the cell that you want to assign some data.

```
@interface ViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
            if ([updatedDateAndTime[i] objectForKey:@"open_house_updated_date"] == selectedDay) {
            NSLog(@"%i th index contains NSMutableDictionary that you want",i);
            //do whatever needed
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    else{
        //define other cells which doesn't contain NSMutableDictionary
    }
    return cell;
}

@end
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot for extending your support. However, the array consists of a lot of NSMutableDictionary objects. Hence, this would not be the case.

Comment: so there must be a criteria to check for right dictionary and what is that?

Comment: `NSString *dateKeySelected = @"open_house_updated_date";`
` NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K != NULL", dateKeySelected]; // Dictionaries having the key`
 `NSArray *filteredArray = [updatedDateAndTime filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateString];`

`NSMutableDictionary *updatedDay = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`
`[updatedDay setObject:selectedDay forKey:@"open_house_updated_date"];`